# sleep until this systemd timer calendar time occurs?

Tags: systemd, systemd-timers

systemd has timers with lots of useful ways to input dates or times. I'm writing a long running data processing script. Is there any command to sleep until a specific systemd time definition occurs? e.g. `systemd-timer-sleep --until-calendar="03:00"`, a commmand which would block until the next 3:00am.

Yes, I know this means my script might run for days, that's OK.

I'm sure I can do this with `date` & `sleep` & calculating the number of seconds until my desired datetime, but I want to know if there's (now) an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this would be something like the following:

```
while [ $(date +%H:%M) != "03:00" ]; do sleep 1; done
```

This will block until the next time it is 3 AM. You can pretty easily modify the format codes to be whatever you'd like.